# GtkEntry and "editing_done" signal

Tags: c, gtk, gtkentry

I have function to set DEVICE in gtk entry field:

```
gboolean device_entry_activate_cb (GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data)
{
    const gchar *text;

    text = gtk_entry_get_text (GTK_ENTRY (entry));

    if (!strcmp( DEVICE, text )
        return FALSE;

    if ( DEVICE )
        g_free( DEVICE );

    DEVICE = g_strdup( text );

    if (0 == strcmp(DEVICE, "auto"))

    /* do something: start printer for example */

    return FALSE;
}

void device_entry_auto_activate_cb(GtkEntry* entry, const gchar* text, gpointer data)
{
    GtkEditable *editable = GTK_EDITABLE (entry);

    text = gtk_entry_get_text (GTK_ENTRY ( entry));

    if (0 == strcmp(text, ""))
        g_signal_emit_by_name(G_OBJECT (editable), "activate");

}
```

and connected with "hide" and "activate" signals

I'd like to automatically activate without press enter key after I typed "auto" text in entry field. Activate after last char "o" is typed in entry.
What I'm doing now is : make the Gtk signal "editing_done" active on the widget.
But it doesn't seem to work, I never get my callback function called.

```
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(entry), "hide", G_CALLBACK(device_entry_activate_cb), app);
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(entry), "activate", G_CALLBACK(device_entry_activate_cb), NULL);
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(entry), "changed", G_CALLBACK(device_entry_auto_activate_cb), NULL);
```

I don't wan't to require an "enter" to "activate" if gtk_entry containe text: auto

UPDATE code that I use.

Comment: More ... code ... needed ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to connect to the **GtkEditable:changed** signal and when the text in the entry is auto, use **[g_signal_emit_by_name](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-Signals.html#g-signal-emit-by-name)** to fake-send the **GtkEntry:activate** signal.